# What is the meaning of "used to show disapproval" in dictionaries?

Tags: meaning, dictionaries

I see some words and phrases in Longman dictionary and there is a sentence at the end of their definition: "used to show disapproval".

I'm not sure what exactly it means.

For example, I looked up the word "obsess" in the dictionary and here is the definition:

> if something or someone obsesses you, you think or worry about them all the time and you cannot think about anything else - used to show disapproval

Comment: It means the said action isn't approved of or liked in general.

Answer (score 2):

This expression basically tells you that the speaker will use this word in order to show his/her disapproval of whatever it refers to. If you compare for example ***to be obsessed with someone*** and ***to think of someone all the time*** (because they are dear to you), you understand that 'obsessed' denotes a negative attitude of the speaker towards the person described.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disapproval) defines *disapproval* as:

> the feeling of having a negative opinion of someone or something:
>
> - Although they said nothing, she could sense their disapproval of her suggestion.